# Comparing a javascript variable with a JSP array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

This is the code I have

```
<script>
function validation () {
    var x=document.getElementById("user").value;
    var y=document.getElementById("user");
    var names="<%=names%>";
    for (var j=0; j<names.length; j++) {
        if (names[j].test(x)) {
            //alert(names[j].match(x));
            return true;
        }
        else{
            y.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is for a login page,2 fields are there as usual username password.
I am checking if the username is there in the database,he can enter the password or else he cant.But this code doesnt go to the password even if the username is right.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not java guy, but you probably need to convert java variable into json for javascript to make  acomparison. Plus you don't check for username and passwords on client-side.

Comment: It seems that the for loop only check if x match to first element in names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.Thnx for the help

this is the answer

```
function validation() {
    var x=document.getElementById("user").value;
    var y=document.getElementById("user");
    var z=document.getElementById("pass");
    var names="<%=names%>";
    names= names.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    names=names.split(", ");
    for (var j=0; j<names.length; j++) {
        if (names[j].localeCompare(x)==0) {
            return true;
        }
        z.removeAttribute("readonly", 0);
    }
    alert("You username is not registered on our databsae");    
    y.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the data type of `names` in java is an `String[]`, the code `<%=names%>` equals to `<%=names.toString()%>`.
So when the jsp is rendered, your javascript code will be something like `var names="[Ljava.lang.String;@5d888759"`. Obviously, it not a valid javascript array definition.

Your need to process your java array first. Add the following code to your jsp(above your javascript code):

```
<%
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("[");
for(String name : names) {
    sb.append("'");
    sb.append(name);
    sb.append("',");
}
if(sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1) == ',') {
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);  //remove tailing ','
}
sb.append("]");
String strNames = sb.toString();
%>
```

And then modify your js code to:

```
var names="<%=strNames%>";
```

After jsp rendered, your js code will be like:

```
var names="['foo','bar']";
```

which is a valid array definition in js. Then it will work.

If the data type of `names` in java is `List<String>`, the solution is similar.

Answer (score 0):

check this out

**CASE 1**

```
         var names='{id:1,key:"Apple"}'; // here names is string
         names.key // will give you error

         // so you need to parse it
         //using the json2.js script:
         var obj = JSON.parse(names);
         obj.key // will give you Apple

         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(names)// in jquery
```

Newer browsers support the JSON object natively. The current version of Crockford's JSON library will only define JSON.stringify and JSON.parse if they're not already defined, leaving any browser native implementation intact.

**CASE 2**

```
         var names={id:1,key:"Apple"}; // here names is object
         names.key // will give you Apple
```

REFERENCE

JSON = > https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js